# Taking images out of SVN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, image

I have a bunch of images in SVN I would like to move out and put on S3. How have you dealt with keeping images out of your ruby on rails apps and out of SVN?

Comment: The question isn't clear enough. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, I really want to reduce the amount of static assets served from my VPS and reduce the footprint of the SVN repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to put your images into your repository. You could still have them on your server, but it doesn't really matter where they're linked from. If you don't use any plugins to manage your assets then you can just remove them from your repository, upload all of them to S3 and update all links pointing to them.

If you do use some kind of plugin like paperclip or attachment_fu then you'll have to tell it where to find your files.

Comment: The one downside I see to this is developers wanting to test images. They would have to test locally, then make sure they put the images to S3 when they deploy the code. IT would work, though.

Comment: You can use two different S3 accounts/buckets for that. One for testing purposes and another for production.